# 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute 'detectMultiscale'

Tags: python

I simply want to detect face and eyes using haarcascade. But this is the error I am receiving.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "L:/Project/1", line 10, in <module>
    faces=face_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray,1.3,5) AttributeError: 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute

'detectMultiscale'
```

This is the code I found on internet

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img=cv2.imread('download.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces=face_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray,1.3,5)
for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    roi_color=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    eyes=eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for(ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: Use `detectMultiScale`, capital `S`, not `detectMultiscale`.

Answer (score 1):

As @roganjosh mentioned in the comments for the question, the problem here is that the method name is not spelled out correctly. The correct function call is:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(...)
```

With the difference being that the 'S' in scale is capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

**A similar code worked for me with the absolute path for both the XML files. The sample is covered below.**

**1. Download XML files from** [https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades]

**2. Mention the absolute path for the XML files (*example below*)**

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Python\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Python\haarcascade_eye.xml')
```