# Error while using OpenCV 4.1.0 for Face detection

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-detection

Using Opencv 4.1.0 for face detection. Error message while calling detectMulitiScale function.

Checked whether OpenCV-contrib was installed

```
import cv2
gray_img=cv2.imread("test_opencv.jpg",0)
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascades_frontalface_default.xml")
faces=face_cascade.detectMulitiScale(gray_img,scaleFactor = 1.05,minNeighbors=5)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 faces=face_cascade.detectMulitiScale(gray_img,scaleFactor = 1.05,minNeighbors=5)
>
> AttributeError: 'cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute
>   'detectMulitiScale'

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804793/cv2-cascadeclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-detectmultiscale)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['cv2.CascadeClassifier' object has no attribute 'detectMultiscale'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804793/cv2-cascadeclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-detectmultiscale)